# Could not find the wordpress page

Tags: urls

One of the pages in my clients wordpress website shows the url
....management.com/home/6120-2

I wanted to modify this page. I couldn't find it within my folders in hosting. 
Could you please help in resolving this.

Answer (score 1):

The page/post on WordPress aren't storage on the filesystem (folders), they are saved on the DataBase, if you want to modify a page, you have to loging into your WordPress [dashboard](https://en.support.wordpress.com/dashboard/), and then visit the page and click on the top bar link to **Edit Page**, you can also go to your dashboard to the page section and find your page `/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page`